# MD5 Round Operations RFC1321

Tags: python, cryptography, md5

According to this [documentation](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt) of md5 function the Step 4 involves rounds of functions where

> Let [abcd k s i] denote the operation
>
> a = b + ((a + F(b,c,d) + X[k] + T[i]) <<< s).
>
> Do the following 16 operations.

I am unsure what the "+" symbolises in this operation, be it addition or bitwise AND. Earlier in the paper it states

> Let the symbol "+" denote addition of words (i.e., modulo-2^32
>      addition). Let X <<< s denote the 32-bit value obtained by circularly
>      shifting (rotating) X left by s bit positions.

I know that [abcd] are 32 bit 'Words' and T[i] is a float (ive converted into 32 bit word and X[k] is a single bit. By doing this function with bitwise AND the result at the end of the function is always a 32 bitstring of FALSE which leads me to think somewhere is going wrong.

This is the python code responsible:

```
    # parse to bitarrays
    xb = bitarray(str(x))
    tb = bitarray(str(t))

    value = b & ((a & F(b,c,d) & xb & tb)) # value always turns false
    value = leftshift(value, s)
    return value
```

And a screenshot of variables watch that may be useful.
[image]

Thanks in advance SO community

Comment: Since the document itself defines `+` as *modulo-2^32 addition* I think it is safe to assume that `+` does not mean bitwise AND, but rather that you add the leftmost 31 bits of the two words together and discard any resulting overflow.

Comment: @BoarGules: leftmost **32** bits.

Comment: I don't understand where the confusion lies. "+" means addition, not bitwise "and". X[k] is *not* a single bit, it is a 32-bit value. You really need to re-read the RFC.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Quite correct. A careless error on my part.

Answer (score 1):

When the specification says `+` means 32 bit addition implement `+` using 32 bit addition instead of bitwise `and`.

When in doubt you can see [other](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pureMD5-2.1.3/docs/src/Data.Digest.Pure.MD5.html#local-1627415749) [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) [implementations](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/2311/crypto/md5/md5.c#130).